# Windows Phone Toolkit Test Framework hangs running tests

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've installed the Windows Phone Toolkit Test Framework to an empty wp8 application using nuget. My main page looks now

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Content = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
    }
}

[TestClass]
class ImageTests : WorkItemTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    [Description("foo")]
    public void dummyTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(false);
    }
}
```

as described in http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/20/windows-phone-toolkit-overview.aspx

The problem is that once I launch the project in emulator and hit the play buttom, the app just displays `Running Tests...`and seems to hang. Any ideas how to get my tests actually executed? This same happens even if I remove the test class entirely.

Comment: Try making your ImageTests class public.

Comment: Didn't help. The problem is that the test runner seems to start running but hangs even when there are no tests.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? No tests get run and it just stays at "running tests" for me too. I am on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

In test class use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting, not Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework namespace.